# Use invocable variable of type List<String> in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, invocable-method

I have an invocable method:

```
@InvocableMethod(Label = 'Submit Privacy Source')
public static void action(ActionRequest[] requestActionInList) {...}
```

ActionRequest is:

```
public with sharing class ActionRequest {
    @InvocableVariable(Label = 'Data Subject ID' Required = true)
    public Id dataSubjectId;

    @InvocableVariable(Label = 'Privacy Source Name' Required = true)
    public String privacySourceName;

    @InvocableVariable(Label = 'Consent Request Names')
    public String[] consentRequestNames;
}
```

When I try to set values for `consentRequestNames` variable in Process Builder it allows to set it as a single string only.

[image]

How to set a list of strings instead of a single string for `consentRequestNames` variable?

Comment: have you tried List<String> requestActionInList as a parameter instead?

Comment: Yes. I've just tried. The same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to pass list as what you want. Try another way of getting list. You can pass multiple parameters but not the list.

Comment: How do you pass multiple parameters? If for example I need to pass more than one string into his 'Consent Request Names' do I enter it as a ';' separated list?

Comment: You can pass semicolon separated string and  put logic inside to process them.